# Main window keeps activating after opening a new window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple Navigator class that keeps instances of my windows and opens them/closes them. When I open a new window from the main window, I need the new window to be on top. Problem is that neither .Focus() nor .Activate() do work. The new window just flashes and then the main window is activated again, even though I never explicitly activate it. The method that I use to open a new window follows:

```cs
public Task OpenDetailAsync(int? deploymentScriptID = null)
{
    if (_detailWindow == null)
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        _detailWindow = new DetailWindow { DataContext = _detailViewModelFactory.Create(deploymentScriptID, this) };
        _detailWindow.Closed += (sender, e) => source.TrySetResult(true);
        _detailWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        _detailWindow.Show();
        _detailWindow.Activate();
        _detailWindow.Focus();
        return source.Task;
    }
    else
    {
        ShowMessageBox("foreign language you wouldn't understand", "lol");
        return null;
    }
}
```

So when I inject an instance of my Navigator class to the main window's DataContext and then use it to open a detail window, the detail window is activated, flashes and then the main window is activated again, which I can clearly see when I use the following delegate in the main window:

```cs
public ListWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Activated += ListWindow_Activated;
}

private void ListWindow_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: It's a bit of crazy to use asynchrony for opening a window... Why do you need a `Task` in this place?

Comment: Well I need to iterate through the collection located in the main ViewModel, then sometimes stop, open the item in detail window, manually edit it, close the window and continue with the iteration. But the problem actually was there even before I made the opening method asynchronous, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: You could make it a modal window of the parent. That will force it to remain on top. _detailWindow.Parent = Application.Current.MainWindow

Comment: Focus activates a window so you don't need both. Wht would focs go back to your parent window? That's what you should ask yourself.  Something you've not shown us is setting focus back to your mainwindow. If you'd put together a minimal reproduction I think you'd probably find it just works.

Comment: I agree with dymanoid BTW. the task stuff is a bad idea here. If it runs in a different thread then you'll get errors due to thread affinity. If it doesn't then it should just be an Action or something instead.

Comment: Thank you for you answers, I'll review them tomorrow. I never set focus back to the main window explicitly, because I always close the detail window before I need focus back on the main window. Also I need to return task because the method works with TaskCompletionSource. It never leaves the UI thread.

Comment: Okay, I've quickly tried bwing's solution and it works just fine, although I need to set .Owner instead of .Parent, which is readonly property. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found out that the problem was completely elsewhere. The detail window is opened from ListView by double clicking on the ListViewItem. I handled the event in main window's UserControl XAML file like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDoubleClick">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenDetail}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewScripts,Path=SelectedItem.DeploymentScriptID}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

It turned out all I needed to do is replace PreviewMouseDoubleClick with MouseDoubleClick.